# javascript remove(selector) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

checkout this:-   [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gespiton/q9nfjby2/)

```
$('body').remove('p')
```

my problem is, when pass selector to remove() function the remove() seems not working,but when I use

```
$('body p').remove()
```

it works fine. so, what's the problem, please help

Comment: [`.remove(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) is equivalent to using [`.filter(selector).remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) rather than `.find(selector).remove()`. Filtering a collection with the `<body>` to only `<p>` elements results in an empty collection, so `.remove()` has no effect.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski  is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `<p>` is a children to `<body>` so use `children()`:-

```
$('body').children('p').remove()
```

```js
$('body').children('p').remove();

// you can use find() also:- $('body').find('p').remove();
```

```css
body {
  outline: 1px solid purple;
}

svg {
  outline: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<p>
hi,there
</p>
</body>
```

The same thing is happening in `$('body p').remove()`.

***Why `$('body').remove('p')` is not working:-***

AS  ***@Jonathan Lonowski*** explained correctly:-

`.remove(selector)` is equivalent to using `.filter(selector).remove()`.  Filtering a collection with the `<body>` to only `<p>` elements results in an empty collection, so `.remove()` has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

`$('body').children('p').remove()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find your p elements in your body

```
$('body').find('p').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this to remove all the 'p' tags recursivly from body

```
$('body').find('p').remove()
```